# Not able to create AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

I have a running micro strategy instance in AWS (Amazon Web Services). I created a snap shot of my running instance, after which I created a AMI using the snap shot. When i tried to create a new instance with the image I was not able to create it. I am getting a failure message.

My currently running AMI is : ami-b1b9cdd8

MY AMI created from the snapshot : ami-817320e8

Kindly help me on the same

Comment: How did you create a AMI from a snapshot? Did you lunch a new instance for the snapshot then created a AMI from that?

Comment: Quite a bit more detail is needed to diagnose the problem. 

Your best bet is probably AWS Support, who can look at your AMI and snapshot and see what's going on.

Comment: What does the "failure message" say?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a (working) AMI from a snapshot of a Windows instance. Instead, create the AMI directly from the instance (not via a snapshot).